# Problem understanding Principal Component Analysis code

Tags: numpy, pca, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Can anyone please explain me this line of code?
P = vectors.T.dot(C.T)
at line 22

I have searched for online documentation but I found nothing.

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import mean
from numpy import cov
from numpy.linalg import eig

# define a matrix
A = array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print(A)
# calculate the mean of each column
M = mean(A.T, axis=1)
print(M)
# center columns by subtracting column means
C = A - M
print(C)
# calculate covariance matrix of centered matrix
V = cov(C.T)
print(V)
# eigendecomposition of covariance matrix
values, vectors = eig(V)
print(vectors)
print(values)
# project data
P = vectors.T.dot(C.T) # Explain me this line
print(P.T)
```

Comment: Scalar product of `vectors.T` and `C.T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vectors.T.dot(C.T)` is the dot product of the transposed array `vectors` with the transposed array `C`

The dot product operation and projections are related as one can use the dot product to obtain the length of a projected vector along a direction (the other vector), when that vector is a unit vector.

As your question is rather vague, I'll let you comment on this answer and adapt it if necessary.

Comment: @HarshalSawant I see you are new to Stack Overflow. When an answer is useful to you, it is a good thing to upvote it. It gives some sort of recognition to the person who took the time to help you and, most importantly, it helps others having a question similar to you to know that the answer has been useful to someone else and hence is worth reading. ;)